# Lua add item to table issue

Tags: lua, lua-table

The goal of the function's below is to check **containers** if there is space for the **new item** and if so add the item to a table with the **containers** name as a key/value or stack ontop of another pre-existing item.

Something goes wrong when the item needs to change one of it's key/value's, it ends up changing all items with the same name to the new key/value.

I can't find any code which iterates over the current items and changes any values apart from *quantity* so I'm assuming it's an error when adding a new item, from my understanding there might be an instancing or referencing issue within the function? I'm very new to lua though.

This is a console output of the function's with some `print()`'s added to give some more context

```
Adding Item: knife
    Not Stackable
    Slot Found in: leg
    Item Added.
...
Current Items:
    knife   1   900 leg
...
Current Containers:
    chest   0
    leg     1
    back    0
    hand    0
...
Adding Item: twig
    Stackable
        No Stack Found.
    ...
    Slot Found in: leg
    Item Added.
...
Current Items:
    knife   1   900 leg
    twig    7   2   leg
...
Adding Item: knife
    Not Stackable
    Slot Found in: hand
    Item Added.
...
Current Items:
    knife   1   900 hand
    twig    7   2   leg
    knife   1   900 hand
...
Current Containers:
    chest   0
    leg     1
    back    0
    hand    1
...
Adding Item: knife
    Not Stackable
    Slot Not Found
    Item Not Added.
...
```

Everything seems to be working apart from the **new item** setting all other items of the same name to the same **container**.

initial function with the **item** passed

```
local stackFree = checkStackFree(item)
local slotFree, slotContainer = checkSlotFree(item)

--If Item was Not Stacked
if not stackFree then
    --If Slot Free & Space Available
    if slotFree then
        item.container = slotContainer
        items[#items+1] = item

        containers:addItems(slotContainer,1)
        containers:addBulk(slotContainer,1)

        return true
    else
    --No Space for New Item
        return false
    end
    --New Item was Stacked
    return true
end
```

example non-stackable item

```
{
    name = "knife",
    type = "weapon",
    qty = 1,
    stackable = false,
    bulk = 900
}
```

example stackable item (stackable items do the same thing once there are no stacks available.)

```
{
    name = "twig",
    type = "misc",
    qty = 1,
    stackable = true,
    stackMax = 20,
    bulk = 900
}
```

checkStackFree()

```
--Check if New Item is Stackable
if item.stackable then
    --Iterate over Current Items
    for i,v in ipairs(items) do
        --Find a match
        if v.name == item.name then
            --Check Matching Item + New Item Quantity less than Max
            if v.qty+item.qty < v.stackMax then
                --Check Matching Item Container has Space
                if containers:getBulk(v.container)+(item.qty*item.bulk) < containers:getMaxBulk(v.container) then
                    --Modify Matching Item Quantity
                    v.qty = v.qty+item.qty
                    return true
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
return false
```

checkSlotFree()

```
--Check Current Items < Max Items
if containers:getItems("chest") < containers:getMaxItems("chest") then
    --Check Current Bulk + New Item Bulk < Max Bulk
    if containers:getBulk("chest")+item.bulk*item.qty < containers:getMaxBulk("chest") then
        return true, "chest"
    end
end
... repeat for other containers

--If no Containers already escaped, We're Full
return false, nill
```

I have also tried without success `table.insert(items, item)` which after reading the link below doesn't sound like it would behave differently in this circumstance.

http://lua-users.org/wiki/TablesTutorial

Answer (score 1):

All makes sense, I wasn't "copying" the table, more just referencing.